# error when importing Django module in visual studio

Tags: django

I am un able to solve this error as I am trying to run it on a django server it keeps throwing these errors

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you installed python deps with pip ? Are you using virtual env ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LucasGrugru yes I have installed python with pip and I am using a virtual environment

Comment: @aleenakotadiya can you show what you have configured in your vscode for python interpreter and virtual env ?

Comment: @LucasGrugru i have added a picture of python and pip configured  and I have installed django in the virtual environment

Comment: @aleenakotadiya If you want to VSCode known where is django and other installed package in virtualenv, you have to configure virtualenv INTO Vscode and interpreter. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments